# Facebook Graph API - Get post_id for posted photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get the **post_id** for the resulting post on the wall / feed (e.g. 987654321_123456789) after publishing a photo to `/photos` instead of the photo **object_id** (e.g. 334455667788)?

When we call the `https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/photos` recource to **publish a photo**, the returned ID (JSON response) will be the **object_id** of the photo

The only way I could think of was to get the entire feed since posting the picture (in case someone else made a post in between) and then getting the post_id for the post that has the object_id == photo_id. That seems a little crude though..

"A way" means it could be FQL (fql=Select...), a search query(search?q=...) or any basic graph resource that I haven't thought of that will provide the exact information.

(We're using Jersey and Jackson to interact with the Facebook Graph API.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im setting his as "answered" as there really seems to be no other way than the described one:

> The only way I could think of was to get the entire feed since posting the picture (in case someone else made a post in between) and then getting the post_id for the post that has the object_id == photo_id. That seems a little crude though..